# Keep background-size: cover, but also enable size auto for iphones?

Tags: css, background-size

In the CSS style file I have this line

```
background-size: cover;
```

But then the background image will not be visible on iPhones. All other phones can see it.

And then if I set size like this

```
background-size: auto;
```

all mobile devices + iPhone can see the background, but the web is the weird. The image does not size well, but you can see some spacing between the image and its container.

What is the proper way to solve this situation?

Comment: could you share more of your code?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.backgroundImage { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%; }
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YQmEQw